# Anonymous Requests with Spring Webflux Security

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-webflux

I am trying to use Spring Webfux Security to secure a path in SPA. The path to be secured is "/**/orderbook" and all other paths should be open to anonymous access. How do I have to configure Spring Security for that? Currently it always asks for a login and not only for the path to be secured.

My Webflux Config:

```
@Bean       
SecurityWebFilterChain springWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) throws Exception {     

    return http
            .csrf().disable()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .logout().disable()
            .securityContextRepository(this.jwtSecContextRepository)
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/**/orderbook").authenticated()
            .anyExchange().permitAll()
            .and().build();
     }
}
```

The JwtSecContextRepository looks like this:

```
    @Component
public class JwtSecurityContextRepository implements ServerSecurityContextRepository {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> save(ServerWebExchange exchange, SecurityContext context) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<SecurityContext> load(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        LinkedList<SimpleGrantedAuthority> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();
        linkedList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USERS"));
        Authentication auth = new JwtAuthenticationToken("user", "password", linkedList);           
        return Mono.just(new SecurityContextImpl(auth));
    }

}
```

I am missing a feature like anonymous access. The SecurityContextRepository tries to provide that but with no success. I seems like the SecurityContextRepository has no effect at all.

Has somebody any idea?

Comment: check if this helps https://github.com/dmendezg/jwt-spring-webflux

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried it and it seems to be that because I am using async servlets with jetty I need to use WebSecurity.